# How to breakdown by field in Opensearch? Kibana to Opensearch migration

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch

In Kibana I have a vertical bar chart with X-axis being timestamp and Y-axis being the median of a field. On top of that, the vertical columns uses a breakdown by top values feature to produce something like this:

[image]

How can I breakdown by field in OpenSearch?

Answer (score 0):

For OpenSearch what you are looking for is to add a `Split series` sub-bucket to the **Buckets** section. You then set the sub-aggregation to `Terms` and select the field you would like to split by. You can then order this alphabetically or by a custom metric.

So the **Buckets** section of your visualisation should look something like this:

- X-axis
- Split Series

  - Sub aggregation: `Terms`
  - Field: `<desired field>`